# Git show commit number

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

Is there a way to show index numbers of commit in

```
    git log
```

command,
git log only show me SHA1 check sum.
Thanks

Comment: As explained in an already given answer, Git doesn't have index numbers. If you explain your end goal someone might be able to suggest another way of accomplishing what you want.

Comment: @MagnusBäck, i want to compare my program version number with commit index number in git

Comment: That's not really an end goal, and since "commit index number" isn't a useful concept in Git your question still cannot be answered. If you want to describe a Git commit with something that's human readable and maybe even relates to your version numbers perhaps [`git describe`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html) can be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Git commits do not have an index number. A git repository is a tree of commits, it is not a list.

git log can order commits in the following ways:

```
Commit Ordering
   By default, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order.

   --topo-order
       This option makes them appear in topological order (i.e. descendant commits are shown before their parents).

   --date-order
       This option is similar to --topo-order in the sense that no parent comes before all of its children, but otherwise things are still ordered in the commit timestamp order.

   --reverse
       Output the commits in reverse order. Cannot be combined with --walk-reflogs.
```

If git log would show you an index number it would change each time you show the commits in a different order (and if you merged in another branch).